# /d2l/api/le/1.0/" grade.getCourseId() "/grades/" gradeId, "PUT"

Tags: api, desire2learn, valence

The problem is that my application sends a large user data, say around 1000+ entries. The API works in a linear fashion where one user grade data is inserted at a time, which results in my product's session timeout. While we can always increase the session timeout at this end, however just wanted to check if D2L provides any API that PUTs/Pushes multiple user grades. Or any alternative approach will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the Valence Learning Framework API does not provide a way to do bulk-creation of grade objects or values. This is a feature that several clients have asked for and it is on the development roadmap for the platform; however, D2L does not yet have a firm estimate on delivery for this functionality.